# how do I find special character in the path string and how many times are they present

Tags: python, string, find

```
pathString="E:\new folder\Study\Batch\test_project_nuke\test_render\testImg_###.jpeg"
```

I tried to first separate the extension and found presence of \t converts string \t tab .

also I tried this way

```
numberOfSplChar=pathString.rfind("#") - pathString.find("#")
print numberOfSplChar
```

and found 1 less..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> pathString="E:\new folder\Study\Batch\test_project_nuke\test_render\testImg_###.jpeg"
> ```
>
> I tried to first separate the extension and found presence of \t
>   converts string \t tab .

That's one issue: a `"\t"` in a string literal means a tab. You either should write `\\t` or put it in a raw string (`r"\t"`).

> also i tried this way
>
> ```
> numberOfSplChar=pathString.rfind("#") - pathString.find("#")
> print numberOfSplChar
> ```
>
> and found 1 less..

Of course. Let's take this simpler string:

```
pathString = "a###b".
```

`rfind()` gives 3, lfind gives 1. The difference is the distance from the 1st to the last, which is one less than the number. So just add 1.

But beware of strings like `'a###b###c###d###e'` - how should they be treated?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the number of "#" in your string, use the [str.count](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method :

```
pathString=r"E:\new folder\Study\Batch\test_project_nuke\test_render\testImg_###.jpeg"
pathString.count("#")
>>> 3
```

If you need to find the extension of your file, use the [os.path.splitext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) method :

```
pathString=r"E:\new folder\Study\Batch\test_project_nuke\test_render\testImg_###.jpeg"
path, extension = os.path.splitext(pathString)
print path
>>> 'E:\\new folder\\Study\\Batch\\test_project_nuke\\test_render\\testImg_###'
print extension
>>> '.jpeg'
```

P.S. : use the `r`(aw string) modifier when you use `\` in your string. In your example, the E:\new" could have been translated in :

```
"""E:
ew"""
```